# brew httpd24 and php70 - php won't render

Tags: php, macos, apache, laravel, homebrew

I'm trying to get httpd24 and php70 running in brew for Laravel local development on El Capitan. Mostly, it's working, but PHP won't render on index load. I had this exact vhosts file running under native mac apache. The issue I was running into was getting a new enough version of Tidy compiled into PHP. I really like the concept of having all of this managed by Homebrew, but I'm having issues with the execution.

brew relevant stuff:

```
    $ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
    $ brew list
apr     freetype    icu4c       nginx       openssl     readline
apr-util    gettext     jpeg        nmap        openssl@1.1 tidy-html5
bash-completion git     libpng      node        pcre        unixodbc
composer    htop        libxml2     nspr        php70       zlib
dnsmasq     httpd24     mysql       nss     php70-tidy
    $ brew services list
Name    Status  User Plist
dnsmasq started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
httpd24 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
mysql   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

I'm running all above services via sudo to get them into LaunchDaemons, since otherwise apache simply refuses to run.

My vhosts file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAlias myuser-mn1.myco.biz
   ServerAlias laravel.localhost
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   LogLevel debug
   UseCanonicalName Off
   ServerAlias myuser-mn1.myco.biz
   ServerAlias laravel.localhost
   AliasMatch ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?(.*)$ /Users/myuser/Code/projects/$1/public/$2
   AliasMatch ^/?$ /Users/myuser/Code/projects/index.php

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key"

   DocumentRoot /Users/myuser/Code/projects
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

   <Directory /Users/myuser/Code/projects>
     Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I had this running under the machine's pre-installed /usr/sbin/apache, I didn't require the line:

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

but on the brew version, omitting "index.php" results in a 403 error when trying to load the page.

Using php .so:

```
   $ cat httpd.conf | grep php
LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.15_8/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

So, at this point, I can get a 200 on index.php, but it just spits out the

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After diff'ing pretty much every file between the native apache configs in /etc/apache2 and the brew apache configs under /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4, I found that the brew apache2 installation for whatever reason omits the AddType directive for php:

```
<IfModule php7_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```